SQL; Ensuring a Condition is Met After the Join
I have these two tables:
CREATE TABLE my_table1 (
    name VARCHAR(50),
    var1 DATE,
    var2 INT
);


INSERT INTO my_table1 (name, var1, var2) VALUES
('john', '2010-01-01', 94),
('john', '2010-01-04', 106),
('john', '2015-01-01', 99),
('alex', '2010-01-01', 96),
('alex', '2018-01-01', 96),
('sara', '2005-01-01', 94),
('sara', '2006-01-01', 90),
('tim',  '1999-01-01', 101);

CREATE TABLE my_table2 (
    name VARCHAR(50),
    var3 DATE,
    var4 CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO my_table2 (name, var3, var4) VALUES
('john', '2001-01-01', 'a'),
('john', '2002-01-01', 'b'),
('alex', '2021-01-01', 'c'),
('alex', '2022-01-01', 'd'),
('sara', '1999-01-01', 'e'),
('sara', '2023-01-01', 'f');

I am trying to answer this problem:
problem 1: for each name in my_table2, find the most recent row (based on date). join this row to my_table1. however, after the join - ensure that the date from my_table2 is greater than the date from my_table1 (if not, then remove). The final result should have the same number of rows as my_table1.
For problem 1, I tried to solve the problem like this:
# problem 1

SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM my_table1 t1
JOIN (
    SELECT name, var3, var4
    FROM (
        SELECT name, var3, var4,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY var3 DESC) as rn
        FROM my_table2
    ) tmp
    WHERE rn = 1
) t2
ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.var1 < t2.var3;

The code partly produces the correct output, but I can't figure out how to include a NA row for John and Tim here
Can someone please show me how to do this correctly?
Thanks!
Note: I tried an approach with the COALESCE function. This produced a row for Tim, but it won't produce wont a row for John:
SELECT t1.*, COALESCE(t2.name, 'NA') as name, t2.var3, t2.var4
FROM my_table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT name, var3, var4
    FROM (
        SELECT name, var3, var4,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY var3 DESC) as rn
        FROM my_table2
    ) tmp
    WHERE rn = 1
) t2
ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.var1 < COALESCE(t2.var3, '9999-12-31');


Push the final WHERE back into the subquery, and use a LEFT JOIN? Hard to say without expected results.

@ charlieface: you mean like this?

"SELECT t1., t2.
FROM my_table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT name, var3, var4
FROM (
SELECT name, var3, var4,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY var3 DESC) as rn
FROM my_table2
) tmp
WHERE rn = 1
) t2
ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.var1 < t2.var3;

Sample data is great, but a [mcve] is also supposed to include the expected result.

| for each name in my_table2, find the most recent row (based on date)
There are 3 distinct names in my_table2 so you need 3 most recent rows of data
Select    *
From    ( Select    NAME,  VAR3, VAR4, 
                    Max(VAR3) Over(Partition By NAME) "LAST_DATE"
          From      my_table2 )
Where     VAR3 = LAST_DATE
--
/*    R e s u l t :
NAME                VAR3     VAR4 LAST_DATE
------------------- -------- ---- ---------
alex                01.01.22 d    01.01.22
john                01.01.02 b    01.01.02
sara                01.01.23 f    01.01.23  */

| join this row to my_table1
| after the join - ensure that the date from my_table2 is greater than the date from my_table1
| (if not, then remove)
| The final result should have the same number of rows as my_table1
Theese instructions are contradictory. If you want the number of rows returned to be the same as number of rows in my_table1 then:
Select      t1.*, t2.VAR3, t2.VAR4
From        my_table1 t1
Left  Join  ( Select    *
              From    ( Select    NAME, VAR3, VAR4, 
                                  Max(VAR3) Over(Partition By NAME) as LAST_DATE
                        From      my_table2 
                      )
              Where     VAR3 = LAST_DATE
            ) t2 ON t2.name = t1.name And
                    t2.LAST_DATE > t1.VAR1

/*    R e s u l t :
NAME               VAR1           VAR2   VAR3       VAR4
------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- -------
alex               01.01.10           96 01.01.22   d
alex               01.01.18           96 01.01.22   d
sara               01.01.05           94 01.01.23   f
sara               01.01.06           90 01.01.23   f
john               01.01.10           94           
john               04.01.10          106           
john               01.01.15           99           
tim                01.01.99          101                    */

But if the task is to remove not matching rows then you can:

put INNER JOIN instead of Left Join.
leave left join and move date condition from join's ON clause to query's Where clause

Select      t1.*, t2.VAR3, t2.VAR4
From        my_table1 t1
Left  Join  ( Select    *
              From    ( Select    NAME, VAR3, VAR4, 
                                  Max(VAR3) Over(Partition By NAME) as LAST_DATE
                        From      my_table2 
                      )
              Where     VAR3 = LAST_DATE
            ) t2 ON t2.name = t1.name 
Where t2.LAST_DATE > t1.VAR1

Both will remove john and tim rows from the result. First one within the join (ON clause) and second after the join (if that is what one of the instructions mean) using Where clause
/*    R e s u l t :
NAME               VAR1           VAR2   VAR3       VAR4
------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- -------
alex               01.01.10           96 01.01.22   d
alex               01.01.18           96 01.01.22   d
sara               01.01.05           94 01.01.23   f
sara               01.01.06           90 01.01.23   f          */


You can get your expected results if you add your where clause in the left join clause:
SELECT t1.*, COALESCE(t2.name, 'NA') as name, t2.var3, t2.var4
FROM my_table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT name, var3, var4
     FROM (
         SELECT name, var3, var4,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY var3 DESC) as rn
         FROM my_table2
          ) tmp
     WHERE rn = 1
     ) t2
ON t1.name = t2.name and t1.var1 < COALESCE(t2.var3, '9999-12-31');

This will give you output like:
name    var1        var2    name    var3       var4
john    2010-01-01  94      NA      null       null
john    2010-01-04  106     NA      null       null
john    2015-01-01  99      NA      null       null
alex    2010-01-01  96      alex    2022-01-01  d
alex    2018-01-01  96      alex    2022-01-01  d
sara    2005-01-01  94      sara    2023-01-01  f
sara    2006-01-01  90      sara    2023-01-01  f
tim     1999-01-01  101     NA      null       null

Hope this is what you needed.

I've used a similar approach to the others above, but I've formatted the code using a CTE for better readability:
WITH CTE AS
(
         SELECT name, var3, var4,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY var3 DESC) as rn
         FROM my_table2
), tmp as
(
  SELECT name, var3, var4 FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT t1.*, COALESCE(t2.name, 'NA') as name, t2.var3, t2.var4
FROM my_table1 t1 LEFT JOIN tmp t2
     ON t1.name = t2.name and t1.var1 < COALESCE(t2.var3, '9999-12-31');

Result



name
var1
var2
name
var3
var4




john
2010-01-01
94
NA
null
null


john
2010-01-04
106
NA
null
null


john
2015-01-01
99
NA
null
null


alex
2010-01-01
96
alex
2022-01-01
d


alex
2018-01-01
96
alex
2022-01-01
d


sara
2005-01-01
94
sara
2023-01-01
f


sara
2006-01-01
90
sara
2023-01-01
f


tim
1999-01-01
101
NA
null
null



